# Extracting a correlation matrix with mvabund functions in R

Tags: r, correlation, glm

Has anyone had experience extracting the computationally estimated correlation matrix when using mvabund in R?  It isn't clear to me where it is located among the objects that any of the analyses create.  The code below is an example of running the function.  I am wondering how you would pull this matrix out of the object called glm.test.

I was using R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

```
library("mvabund")

#generating some fake data
species_data<-data.frame()

for(i in 1:100){
    species_data<-rbind(species_data, rpois(100,round(runif(1,1,100)))) 
}
#generating a vector of treatments
treatments<-c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50))

#turning species data into an mvabund object
species_data<-mvabund(species_data)

#running the manyglm() function
glm.test<-manyglm(species_data~treatments,family="negative.binomial")
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example from which you would like the matrix extracted?

Comment: Please insert information into your question. To help you out in future endeavors, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).